# Terraform throwing invalid subnet range error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I keep getting the following error while I try to create a subnet using terraform. No issues creating subnet using aws console. Could someone help me?

```
Error: error creating subnet: InvalidSubnet.Range: The CIDR '192.168.1.0/24' is invalid.
    status code: 400
```

Code to create VPC:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc_worker" {
  provider             = aws.region-worker
  cidr_block           = "198.168.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  tags = {
    Name = "master-vpc-jenkins"
  }
}
```

Code to create subnet:

```
#Create subnet in us-west-2
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_1_worker" {
  provider   = aws.region-worker
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.vpc_worker.id
  cidr_block = "192.168.1.0/24"
}
```

Terraform version: 0.12.29

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your VPC is `198.168.0.0/16`, but subnet is `192.168.1.0/24` (note 198 and 192). Please change VPC to `192.168.0.0/16`.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this, it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting subnet ip outside vpc ip range.

you can refere [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDiGBIOq7ec) about cidr.